# Use comparison statement as parameter in function to then pass as condition in while loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop

Imagine I had some function like this:

```
def func(condition):
    while condition:
        pass
```

Is there any way that I can pass a comparison as condition, for example `func(50 > x)`, but then instead of it executing as `while False` (x would be some value under 50), it does `while 50 > x` (I want to do something like x += 1, so the loop stops eventually)?
I want to do this because I will have the same function in two different situations, and each of them has a while loop, but the condition has to be different from one another. What I did until now is pass another argument into `func`, so `def func(condition,situation)`, and then I would do `while 50 > x if situation == 1 else True`. However, I believe the way I am trying to do it, would be faster, because in the way I have been doing it thus far, after each loop, not only would `50 > x` or `True` have to be evaluated again, but also if `situation == 1`.

This is about what I want to do

```
limit = 50
start = 0

def func(condition)
    while condition:
        pass
        start += 1

# once I need the function like this, once I need it with True, so the loop runs forever in that case
func(limit > start)

func(True)
```

Comment: Typically, you would pass a callable as an argument, and let the code inside the function call it from the while loop. Something like `def func(p): while p(): ...`.

Comment: Just edited it, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah, fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by passing a comparison function and the desired parameters? Something like this:

```py
comparison_a = lambda x, y: x > y
comparison_b = lambda x, y: x <= y
```

(assuming your second condition is something like `x <= y`)
This creates two lambda (for simplification) functions that perform the desired comparison with the parameters `x` and `y`

Then you create your function as:

```py
def func(comparison, start, limit):
    while comparison(start, limit):
        start += 1
```

And call it as:

```py
limit = 50
start = 30

func(comparison_a, 50, 30)
```

Optionally, you could use the `operator` module, which implements python operators as functions. For the `greater than` operator you have `operator.gt`. As an example:

```py
import operator

limit = 50
start = 30

func(operator.gt, 50, 30)
```

Comment: Note that `operator.gt` will probably be more efficient `lambda x, y: x > y`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot about `operator`

Comment: Edited my post for more details, would appreciate if you took a look at it

Comment: There you go, added the example

Answer (score 0):

While I would advise against dynamic parameters like this, you could use the built-in `eval` method, which takes a string of Python and evaluates it inline.

```
def func(condition: String):
    while eval(condition):
        pass
```